# How can BeagleBone Black be used as Mass Storage Device?

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb, beagleboneblack, usb-mass-storage

Is it possible to use the BB as Mass Storage Device?

I want it to be connected to an audio player that can read files from USB connectivity (such as USB flash drive) **and act as data storage device containing one specific folder** (and its sub-folders) from the file system (if possible, on a flash drive connected to the board.).

As the device specs says, it has connectivity of:

- USB client for power & communications
- USB host

Operating system will probably be Ubuntu but can be changed.

What drivers or configurations needs to be done in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The latest images have already the mass storage usb gadget active, so a mass storage peripheral should be recognized by your system upon connection.
A quick google search reveals [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/El1i9h7UzjQ) about a user trying to *disable* the USB MS gadget:

From the discussion, the files where the magic happens are:

- Debian: `/opt/scripts/boot/am335x_evm.sh`
- Ubuntu: `/opt/scripts/boot/am335*`
- Armstrong: `/usr/bin/g-ether-load.sh`

In my Debian image the line you want to modify is:

```
modprobe g_multi file=${gadget_partition} cdrom=0 stall=0 removable=1 nofua=1 iSerialNumber=${SERIAL_NUMBER} iManufacturer=Circuitco  iProduct=BeagleBone${BLACK} host_addr=${cpsw_1_mac}
```

and the corresponding `$gadget_partition` variable that is set just before that in order to customize the folder you want to expose.

Note that the g_multi gadget in its standard configuration presents 3 different devices: an ethernet interface, a mass storage peripheral and a serial interface. If you want to customize the parameters you can refer to the [g_multi documentation (kernel.org)](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/usb/gadget_multi.rst)