# Beagleboard Black: folder for usb drive

Tags: filesystems, usb, beagleboard

I have got a BeagleBoard Black (Industrial) running Debian (not fixed to it) and would like to use the USB mass storage feature to exchange data in between the BB and the USB Host it is connected to.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546269/how-can-beaglebone-black-be-used-as-mass-storage-device) question, but it seems outdatet, the /opt/scripts/boot/am335x_evm.sh file now uses libcomposite which seems not to like to work with folders but only with .img or .iso files.

If I create an .img file and mount it on the host and the BB simultaneously, any change made after mounting it is not propagated to the respective other device.

How can I make the BB expose a folder to the USB Host?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok, [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/usb/mass-storage.txt) document is pretty clear about it:

> BEWARE that if a file is used as a backing storage, it may not be
>   modified by any other process. This is because the host assumes the
>   data does not change without its knowledge. It may be read, but (if
>   the logical unit is writable) due to buffering on the host side, the
>   contents are not well defined.